# Root Authentication failed after update in CentOS 7

Tags: authentication, vps, centos7, update, upgrade

I'm newbie to Server staff, 
I try use this command via ssh to update CentOs 7:

yum update

Or

yum upgrade

But after update i reboot VPS and try to login in via root account then authentication failed.

It's seems root password changed after update.

Answer (score 0):

How are you logging in to root ? 
at the login prompt ? 
or using su ?

While not super familiar with centos. the update may of disabled ssh root login but you may be able to run something like sudo bash with your root password, from your normal account.

Cheers
Roygul